# How to get the number of sibling rows matching multiple classes in jquery

Tags: jquery

i need to get the number of sibling rows that may have styleA or styleB. this is what i have, i just get 0, even though there should be a number returned...

```
$row.siblings('tr').find('.styleA, .styleB').length;
```

Comment: Can you show some HTML? Hard to tell why this isn't working without knowing what `$row` refers to.

Comment: Did you try `$row.siblings('tr.styleA, tr.styleB').length;`?

Comment: May be you just need: `$row.find('.styleA, .styleB').length;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one (as i understood)

```
$row.siblings('tr.styleA,tr.styleB').length;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get elements with context of $row parent.

```
$('.styleA,.styleB', $row.parent()).length
```

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
$row.siblings('tr').filter('.styleA, .styleB').length;
```